# How can I step down 134V efficiently for the high side voltage supply for an AMC1200BDWVR?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, differential-amplifier

I am using a [fully-differential isolation amplifier](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/amc1200.pdf?ts=1704317210205&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). I want to make the high side regulated voltage of 5 V with as few components as possible, so I have built a “resistor-diode” regulator as shown in the schematic. I am unsure if this is appropriate for voltages around 134 V because the resistor I used is 2 kΩ (SMD 0603 package) and it might dissipate about 3 W of power and burn out.

How would you solve this problem?

[image]

B2- is high-side ground, and B+ is high-side positive.

**EDIT:**

I have thought of another way to solve this problem using an [SSP7785-3.3V](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2108072230_Shanghai-Siproin-Microelectronics-SSP7785-3-3V_C2845051.pdf) linear regulator. It accepts 450VDC which is more than enough for my purposes and converts it to 3.3 V which in the AMC1200's datasheet is an acceptable voltage source. I have added a new schematic. Will this be sufficient? Does anyone know what the heck an EP pin is? It's not mentioned in the datasheet.

[image]

Comment: Surely that would be 8W? The zener is 5V so the resistor drops 134-5 = 129V, and 129^2/2k = 8.3W. "EP" = "Exposed Pad", the heatsinking connection, usually can be grounded. Do you have any other requirements behind this application? Is the ~10mA idle consumption, or the couple-watt power dissipation, a problem? Do you have the space to dissipate that heat effectively? Also, what is the V+ range?

Comment: @TimWilliams yep you are likely correct I did not take the diode into account. The problem is that the voltage range is from 20v to 134v so it is quite wide. Like 20k resistor works at 84v however it does not work at 30v. Ideally I would like it to not waste heat or as little as possible and also I have limited space on the pcb so I cannot place large package resistors.

Comment: The SSP7785 is not a good choice if the input voltage goes below 50V.  The datasheet mentions in several places that it requires a minimum input voltage of 50V.

Comment: @JRE Having a view on the datasheet again, yes you are correct. there aren't very many options on LCSC.com.

Answer (score 1):

> **EDIT:** i have thought of another way to solve this problem. using SSP7785-3.3V LDO. it accepts 450VDC which is more than enough for my purposes and converts it to 3.3v which in the AMC1200's datasheet is an acceptable voltage source. I have added a new schematic will this be sufficient?

High-side supply current of the amplifier is 5.5 mA but reaches 8 mA according to the datasheet. The LDO IC you linked is capable of delivering at least 10.5 mA, so it appears to be sufficient.

The LDO is no different than a voltage divider, therefore the input-output voltage difference drops across it, which is about 130 VDC. So the load current dissipates a power across it, which is about 130 x 0.0055 = 0.7W (typ) or 1.05W at max. For this level of dissipation the temperature rise of the IC will be ~40°C although the conditions that this number applies to are not given. Remember that without proper thermal design the IC may go into thermal shutdown.

NOTE: If the B+ voltage's maximum possible value is higher than 134 VDC then the dissipation (therefore the temperature rise) will be higher.

> ... Also if anyone knows what the heck is an EP pin? it's not mentioned in the datasheet(?)

`EP` stands for "Exposed Pad". Its main purpose is to provide a path for heat dissipation. To keep the answer short, I will not dive into the details about how to use the EP. There are numerous app notes and tutorials online, such as [this](https://www.analog.com/en/design-notes/exposed-pads-a-brief-introduction.html), [this](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/thermal-design-with-exposed-pad-packages/) and [this](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/engineering-bulletin/EB806.pdf). You can find more by googling "exposed pad thermal" or similar keywords.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. The voltage range is from 20v to 134v and a resistor diode divider is no good since I need to change resistor values every time my voltage rises to keep the losses down. I understand what an ep pad does now.  So I shall use the chip with proper thermal design?

Comment: @ManeGote `The voltage range is from 20v to 134v and a resistor diode divider is no good` for such a wide range you should've started with a regulator in the first place. `So I shall use the chip with proper thermal design?` yes. Pay attention to the creepage & clearance. Have a look at IPC standards for details.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be a decent way to reduce high voltage.

[image]

The first is what I had before and the second is the proposed better design. (Credit: Sensacell) Of course, for the first one, the resistor value picked is not good but there's no point in picking a good value for it to become useless if the voltage is varied. The second one is a lot more efficient with varied voltage.

This being said I did not use this circuit to have voltage for my chip since I cannot afford to dissipate heat unnecessarily. I ended up using a [B0505S-1WR3](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2110272330_DEXU-Electronics-B0505S-1W_C2912568.pdf) voltage isolator module.

This schematic was used:

[image]

The schematic includes +5V and GND that are isolated from the high voltage and this voltage was generated to power other logic for the receiving end of the AMC1200.

Comment: How do you get that figure of 29.3% efficiency? I calculate 2.8% efficiency for the second circuit. The theoretical maximum possible efficiency for a linear regulator stepping 150 V down to 5 V is 3.33%, so I don't see how you got almost 30%.

Comment: If you aren't switching or have memory elements to store power, the only way to regulate voltage is to change the load and this means burning up power in resistive loads for regulation. Make sure you are using real circuit elements not superconducting ideal components

Comment: @Hearth this is my bad, i seem to have put the decimal in the wrong place when calculating. i will edit my answer. thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

Using that single special HV linear regulator on the market is risky.

Luckily you can make a shunt regulator with a mosfet and a zener diode, or even TL-431.
They are very reliable if you pick the right mosfet capable of linear operation.
It will be stable, but not accurate, but it's a shunt pre-regulator and is not the most efficient.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJGfjk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You pick the output voltage based on the zener voltage.
Start with zener of 5~9V and see what you get.
I think it can work with a TO-220 mosfet on a tiny sheetmetal heatsink.
(eg: 8 mA * 120V drop = 0.96 W)

Put a small linear regulator after is and you're all set.
Doesn't need to be accurate, the AMC1200 has an internal reference.

---

Obviously the above will take quite a lot of board space. HV caps, a mosfet with heatsink...
So maybe another option is to use the cheap isolated DC-DC converter SIP packages, like the Traco Power TEA 1-0505HI. You can use an unregulated one because the AMC's internal ref.
Drop a pair of 1206 resistors ensure the required minimum load to stay within the voltage ratings of the AMC (max 5.5V).
Literally 4 components. (dc-dc, resistors, small cap)